# Using v-for data as v-model value from object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

I'm trying to add a default value to the radio button on page load. I'm looping over a json object by using v-for then trying to use the value in v-model of the radio group so that there would be a default value. For some the radio group doesn't take the v-for value. If I try to print out the current value in the v-for it works.

You'll notice that it prints out the value 3 above the radio buttons but the radio doesn't take that value 3 even though I tried to bind it with v-model

```
      <v-card>
    <v-card-text>

      <h3>Team</h3>
      {{ item.selectedTeam }}

      <h3>Student(s) clearly defined a problem</h3>
      {{ item.question1 }}
      <br>


        <label></label>
        <v-flex xs12>
        <v-radio-group v-model="item.question1" :mandatory="false" row error-messages>
            <v-radio  color="#0495c9" label="0" value="0"></v-radio>
            <v-radio  color="#0495c9" label="1" value="1"></v-radio>
            <v-radio  color="#0495c9" label="2" value="2"></v-radio>
            <v-radio  color="#0495c9" label="3" value="3"></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
        </v-flex>


    <h3>There is a need for this product/service</h3>
    {{ item.question2 }}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code, not the screenshot!

Comment: I added the code can you vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `item.question1` is of `Number` type and not a `String`.

If `item.question1` must be of `String` type, update your code as this:

```
<v-radio label="3" value="'3'"></v-radio>
```

Notice the single quotation marks, this will treat the value of the radio as `String`.